# Helices on squeezed Coke can

Tags: differential-geometry

Helices on a circular cylinder ( like a Coke-can with base and top discs cut off ) radius $R$ with single parameter helix angle $\theta$

$$ (x,y,z) = R( \cos \theta , \sin  \theta,  \theta \cot \beta ) $$

are squeeze-deformed so that  a  circumference $ 2 \pi R$  remains the same length$ = 4 a E(e)$ where $E$ is a complete elliptic integral, being isometrically mapped to an ellipse major axis $a$ and eccentricity $e.$

EDIT1:

How do the (unbent) normal curvature and torsion $ (\kappa_n, \tau_g)=(\sin ^2\beta/R,\sin \beta \cos \beta/R)$  change?

How to find new  coordinates $  (x_s,y_s,z_s)  ? $ A related similar earlier post of mine:

[Coke-can deformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081607/squeezed-cylinder-parametrization)

Comment: If you want to use the natural parameter then won't you need (as a limiting case) also the points of the ellipse parametrized by $s$. IIRC that cannot be done with elementary functions, so this may be a tall order as well. Or, at least it is likely to involve elliptic integrals.

Comment: $\theta/s = \sin \beta/ R $ before deformation,can be converted. For $ z_{min}<z<z_{max} $ only $z=0$ circle remains planar. I did not imagine it could be tough, given that $ k_g, K$ remain zero, but am unable to proceed further, could be unaware of what else goes into its setting up ... to obtain  for each helix point elliptic functions  as a function of $e$.. so the helices may be computer animated/manipulated.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please indicate steps leading to ode/pde, perhaps with  Gauss-Codazzi. I hope cylinder deformations would interest all,  Regards.

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my compass :-(